# How can I automatically set my status to Available when I log in?

Tags: 11.04, empathy, autostart, instant-messaging, memenu

This is the first thing I do after logging in:

[image: screenshot]

How can I make it happen automatically?

Comment: Same problem / solution on 12.04 LTS for the record.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make the default Ubuntu IM application Empathy start automatically when you log in, the following instructions are from [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/how-to-auto-start-gwibber-empathy/):

> Empathy requires a little bit of a
> kick to get going on login.
>
> You would be forgiven for thinking
> that checking the ‘Automatically
> connect on start-up’ box in Empathy’s
> preferences pertained to starting on
> system login. It doesn’t, the start-up
> in this case refers to Empathy’s start
> up – not your computer’s.
>
> We can make it start on login by going
> to System > preferences > startup
> applications > new item and entering
> the following information in the
> relevant fields:
>
> Name: Empathy
>
> Command: empathy -h

Comment: @fluteflute: Thanks for making the answer for meaningful... :-)

Comment: I still think that's pretty counter intuitive.. am I the only one?

Answer (score 5):

this script will automatically set status to "unavailable" when screen is locked or screensaver is activated, and will bring it back to available (online) when screensaver is closed!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
from gi.repository import TelepathyGLib as Tp
from gi.repository import GObject
loop = GObject.MainLoop()
am = Tp.AccountManager.dup()
am.prepare_async(None, lambda *args: loop.quit(), None)
loop.run()

screensaver_started = 0
running = 0

while 1:
    active = 0
 out = ""
 pid = 0

 if screensaver_started == 0:
     # Don't do anything if the screensaver isn't running
     s = os.popen("pidof gnome-screensaver")
     spid = s.read()
     s.close()
     if len(spid) > 0:
         screensaver_started = 1
 else:
     h = os.popen("gnome-screensaver-command -q", "r")
     out = h.read()
     active = out.find("inactive")
     h.close()

     if active < 0 and running == 0:
         am.set_all_requested_presences(Tp.ConnectionPresenceType.OFFLINE, 'Offline', "")
         running = 1
     elif active > 0 and running == 1:
         am.set_all_requested_presences(Tp.ConnectionPresenceType.AVAILABLE, 'available', "")
         running = 0
     time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: nice solution but most newbies turn away from Linux when they encounter such a script for such a simple need.