# Can I log in as invisible when using empathy?

Tags: empathy, online-accounts

I am using empathy to access MSN and Google talk.

Every time I log in, my status is busy, and I have to change it to invisible.  I wonder if I can save the setting of being invisible upon logging in?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open your **Empathy Messenger** . click at **Edit** and select **Accounts .**

It will open all your accounts , from the accounts  **disable the people near by account** .then you can set your status to Invisible .

Comment: Thanks! After I disable people nearby account, I don't see where I can permanently set my status to invisible for my other accounts?

Comment: you have added all your accounts to Empathy ? Then if those Accounts supports status invisible , then you can make it by setting the status to invisibale. it will applied for all your other accounts .

Comment: I set invisible。 After I log out and log  in again, my status is back to available， and I have to set it again.

Comment: ok follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/40842/how-can-i-automatically-set-my-status-to-busy-when-empathy-starts

Answer (score 0):

Some account types don't support setting your status to invisible.

In Empathy, I've noticed that if you are logged into any such account, then your overall status won't remain showing as invisible, even if some accounts do support an invisible status.  Now, I don't know if that actually means that you *are* still invisible on those accounts that allow it but not on the ones that don't, or if you are then visible on all - you may have to experiment.

But, start disabling accounts until you figure out which one is not supporting invisible mode.  As Raja's answer describes, that may include disabling the "People near by" account if you are using it.